# "to your own private" - what is the meaning in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> I could totally relate to this someday.
>   To conquer the world and then fade out **to your own private** and
>   peaceful happiness away from it all with only your family sounds close
>   to heaven.

**to your own private** - what is the meaning in this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

The adjectives **private** and **peaceful** both modify the noun **happiness**.

The way to understand the whole phrase is like this:

> …to fade out to your own **private and peaceful happiness** away from it all…
>
> …to fade out to your own happiness, which is simultaneously **private and peaceful**, away from it all…

Comment: I kind of find this wording strange - "private happiness" - in OP's quote. Also, may be the sentence could use a pair of commas around *"away from it all with only your family" * to set it off as a parenthetical. If this is in fact essential information (i.e., with your family) then *"away from it all"* is serving no purpose - *"fade out"* already does that. Would you agree?

Comment: @AIQ You could say that _a private happiness_ is a kind of figure of speech: regarding happiness as a place rather a state of mind. So, it suggests that this happiness is like a secluded backyard or country estate. I understand _away from it all_ as adding meaningful emphasis, explicitly bringing up "it all" (the bustling, competitive social world, like "[the cares of the curia](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/57620/6700)") as something to get away from, even though this is implied by _with only your family._

Comment: @AIQ Now that I think about it a little more, _a private happiness_ is a different [figure of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy): it refers to the person's happy living situation as if it were the feeling of happiness experienced while in that situation.